# Manual database connection and control populating error

Tags: sql, vb.net

Ok, So this is my first attempt at a manual database form and I am failing...  I cannot for the life of me figure out why it is not populating the grid view or the textboxes. I have a Data Class that builds the data sets and such and in the Form Class is where the controls are filled.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? I am a noob with database applications.

Here is my Data Class:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Data

Public Class DataClass

Private CategoriesProductsDataSet As NORTHWNDDataSet


'Table adapters for product form
Private CategoriesTableAdapter As NORTHWNDDataSetTableAdapters.CategoriesTableAdapter
Private ProductTableAdapter As NORTHWNDDataSetTableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter


'Declare data relation for the product form
Private CategoriesToProducts As DataRelation


'================================================================
'Create constructor for class
Public Sub New()

    Try
        With Me

            'Instantiate the data sets
            .CategoriesProductsDataSet = New NORTHWNDDataSet

            'Instantiate the table adapters 
            .ProductTableAdapter = _
                New NORTHWNDDataSetTableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter
            .CategoriesTableAdapter = _
                New NORTHWNDDataSetTableAdapters.CategoriesTableAdapter


            'Assign the products data relation to the dataset
            .CategoriesToProducts = CategoriesProductsDataSet.Relations!CategoriesToProducts


            'Fill the dataset using the fill method of the table adapters
            .ProductTableAdapter.Fill(.CategoriesProductsDataSet.Products)
            .CategoriesTableAdapter.Fill(.CategoriesProductsDataSet.Categories)


        End With

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error in data class", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)

    End Try

End Sub

'================================================================

Public Function GetCategoriesProductsDataSet() As NORTHWNDDataSet

    'Return the data set
    Return CategoriesProductsDataSet

End Function
```

And here is the Product Form:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Data

'Module: ProductForm
'Abstract:      This form displays all product information from the database 
'for the employee to edit or add to.


Public Class ProductForm


'Declare module-level variables
Private CategoriesProductsData As DataClass
Private CategoriesProductsDataSet As NORTHWNDDataSet

Private CategoriesTableAdapter As  _
    NORTHWNDDataSetTableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter
Private ProductsTableAdapter As  _
    NORTHWNDDataSetTableAdapters.CategoriesTableAdapter
```

These two lines are commented out because it tell me there is already Friends WithEvents made for these two binding sources. Although I can't find them.

```
'Private WithEvents ProductsBindingSource As BindingSource
'Private WithEvents CategoriesBindingSource As BindingSource

Private AddingBoolean As Boolean
Private ClosingBoolean As Boolean
Private EditingBoolean As Boolean

Private GridInitializedBoolean As Boolean
Private CategoryIDString As String   'holds the category id to filter the data

'===============================================================
Private Sub ProductForm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
```

This Block of code is what is producing the error:

```
    Try
        CategoriesProductsData = New DataClass
        CategoriesProductsDataSet = New NORTHWNDDataSet

        CategoriesProductsDataSet = _
            CategoriesProductsData.GetCategoriesProductsDataSet

        'Set up binding sources
        ProductsBindingSource = New BindingSource
        CategoriesBindingSource = New BindingSource

        'Set the data source and data member
        With CategoriesBindingSource
            .DataSource = CategoriesProductsDataSet
            .DataMember = "Products"
            .Sort = "CategoryID"
        End With

        With ProductsBindingSource
            .DataSource = CategoriesBindingSource
            .DataMember = "ProductsToCategories"
        End With


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Database Error", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)

    End Try
```

It throws up my message box so I'm assuming it is not connecting to the database properly.

```
    'Establish record count
    CategoriesBindingSource.MoveLast()
    CategoriesBindingSource.MoveFirst()

    'Bind the textboxes
    CategoryIDTextBox.DataBindings.Add("text", _
                    CategoriesBindingSource, "CategoryID")
    CategoryNameTextBox.DataBindings.Add("text", _
                    CategoriesBindingSource, "CategoryName")
    DescripRichTextBox.DataBindings.Add("text", _
                    CategoriesBindingSource, "Description")

    'Initialize binding for Products data grid view
    If Not GridInitializedBoolean Then

        'Bind and format the grid
        ProductsDataGridView.DataSource = _
            ProductsBindingSource
        SetUpGridColumns()
        GridInitializedBoolean = True

    End If

    'Filter the products by category ID
    ProductsBindingSource.Filter = "CategoryID = '" & _
        CategoryIDTextBox.Text & "'"

End Sub

'===============================================================
'Create a sub routine to set up the grid columns and set the
'column widths.

Private Sub SetUpGridColumns()

    Try

        With Me.ProductsDataGridView
            'Set up column headers
            .Columns!category_id.HeaderText = "CategoryID"
            .Columns!product_id.HeaderText = "ProductID"
            .Columns!prodName.HeaderText = "Name"
            .Columns!supplier_id.HeaderText = "SupplierID"
            .Columns!quantity.HeaderText = "Quantity/Unit"
            .Columns!unit_price.HeaderText = "Unit Price"
            .Columns!in_stock.HeaderText = "Units In Stock"
            .Columns!on_order.HeaderText = "Units Ordered"
            .Columns!reorder.HeaderText = "Reorder Level"
            .Columns!discontinued.HeaderText = "Discontinued"

            'Set up column widths
            .Columns!category_id.Width = 100
            .Columns!product_id.Width = 75
            .Columns!prodName.Width = 30
            .Columns!lsupplier_id.Width = 75
            .Columns!quantity.Width = 35
            .Columns!unit_price.Width = 50
            .Columns!in_stock.Width = 75
            .Columns!reorder.Width = 90
        End With

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error!  It was a simple mistake.

I had:

```
With ProductsBindingSource
     .DataSource = CategoriesBindingSource
     .DataMember = "ProductsToCategories"
End With
```

Should have been:  (Used the binding source instead of the data set) : /

```
 With ProductsBindingSource
            .DataSource = CategoriesProductsDataSet
            .DataMember = "products"
            .Sort = "ProductID"
```